# Loading Dynamic TreeTable

Tags: jquery, dynamic, treetable

I have currently using the JQuery TreeTable plug-in (http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/). The plug-in is pretty great except my web page depends on dynamic content and when I append data to the table, there's no formatting. It becomes almost like a regular table(The  table loses the formatting such as indentation, ability to expand and collapse nodes etc). My question thus is: Is there any way I can work around this problem or is there another JQuery plug-in that's better for the kind of dynamic functionality I am after?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use appendBranchTo(destination), for dynamic appending of tree nodes.